# Confused by this `find` command in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I have a bash script, created by someone that is no longer able to explain the meaning, that is used for auto TARing a folder and backing it up. At the moment I'm confused with the final line:

```
find '/home/_backups/pokebrawl' -mtime +6 -type f -delete
```

The full script is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Purpose = Backup of Important Data
#Created on 17-1-2012
#Author = Hafiz Haider
#Version 1.0
#START
TIME=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%T")
FILENAME=pokebrawl-$TIME.tar.gz
SRCDIR=/home/servers/brawl/world
DESDIR=/home/_backups/pokebrawl
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
find '/home/_backups/pokebrawl' -mtime +6 -type f -delete
#END
```

Comment: No follow up questions, one question per question. You can ask as many questions as you like. Therefore click ask question, then ask another question, don't add it to the bottom of another.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `find` command will delete any regular file in or below the `/home/_backups/pokebrawl` directory that is more than seven days old (or more precisely, not modified within the last week).

It should *probably* read

```
find "$DESDIR" -mtime +6 -type f -delete
```

or

```
find "${DESDIR:?Not set correctly}" -mtime +6 -type f -delete
```

as there is a perfectly good variable holding that directory name already.  The second variation would cause an error if `DESDIR` for some reason was empty or unset.

I'm assuming this is a way of keeping only the last week's worth of backups. I would suggest using something like `borgbackup` or `restic` instead, as these would be able to keep backups for a lot longer without using much more space (even hourly backups for a year wouldn't take much space at all if the data wasn't changing much). They do deduplication of data and `borgbackup` additionally supports compression (both support remote backups and encryption too).

To run the script every 24 hours (at midnight), use a cron job.

First, issue the command `crontab -e`.  This would open an editor with the current crontab for the active user (this may or may not be an empty file).

Then add

```
@daily /path/to/the/script.sh
```

(where `path/to/the/script.sh` is the pathname of the script).

Save and exit the editor.

The script would now be called at midnight, even night.

Would you want to run the script at, say, 13:30 every afternoon, add the following as the crontab entry instead:

```
30 13 * * * /path/to/the/script.sh
```

See the crontab manual on your system for details on how to write a crontab schedule (`man 5 crontab`).

Comment: On the *It should probably read* aspect : I've seen some scripters deliberately avoid using an environment variable when doing this type of `find`/`delete` operation, in case some doofus forgets to set `$DESDIR` or sets it to "/" or somesuch by mistake.

Comment: @steve Well, if `DESDIR` is changed and the `find` command not updated, it would fail to clean up the correct directory.  It would possibly be helpful to use `${DESDIR:?Not set correctly}` or something similar instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
find '/home/_backups/pokebrawl' -mtime +6 -type f -delete
```

This finds all the files in the directory `/home/_backups/pokebrawl` that haven't been modified in the last `+6` days and deletes them. NOTE: `+6` equates to 7 days.

Look in `man find` to see how these switches work:

```
$ man find
...
   -mtime n
          File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments 
          for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation 
          of file modification times.
```

On Redhat distros you can simply put this script in the directory `/etc/crondaily` and it'll run every day. You can see that there are other scripts there already which you can use as examples:

```
$ sudo ls -l /etc/cron.daily/
total 12
-rwx------. 1 root root 219 Aug  1  2017 logrotate
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 618 Mar 17  2014 man-db.cron
-rwx------. 1 root root 208 Nov  4  2016 mlocate
```